# Swift Scroll View not Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

```
import UIKit

class ContactViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 800)
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

For the past 2 days I have been trying to get my scroll view to work and its not working.  I am very very new to swift and have no idea what to do. The app itself will run however it will simply not scroll up and down !!!! help please i am desperate !!!!

Comment: Does the scroll view show up as you expect? You can verify this by setting a background color on the scroll view. `scrollView.backgroundColor = .blue`

Comment: You have an @IBOutlet which would imply your scroll view is coming from a storyboard. In this case there is no need to explicitly add it as a subview (in fact, doing so should give you an error.). Retrieving the view controller from the storyboard will do this for you. What/how have you added content to the scrollview?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've created the scroll view as a separate class under one of my scenes (if that makes any sense, i'm very new to swift!) how do i retrieve the view controller from the storyboard ?? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @nathan I tried that and the colour did pop up as i expected !

Comment: You link the scroll view by dragging from "new referencing outlet" to the view controller object in your scene navigator and selecting the outlet

Comment: @Paulw11 I am trying to do that right now and it's telling me "Use of undeclared type 'UIScrollVIew"